# Перевод сайта php

Tags: php

Не очень много практики в этом деле,поэтому хочется профессионального мнения на сколько правильна данная структура.

Таблица `Langs` c полями `id, name` и таблица 'Vars' с полями `'id, var_key, name'`

В поле `vars.name` храню массив такого вида `ключ->значение`,где ключ это `id` языка а значение сам перевод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Какое это отношение имеет к php, если это вопрос баз данных, причем реляционных. 2. Структура может быть как правильной - в случае если данные как есть идут куда то выше и там с ними работают и при этом в sql поиск идет только по ID, так и катастрофически не правильной, если у вас есть возможность/необходимость работать с частями той строки в самом sql

Comment: Поиск идет по полю var_key и далее из массива names получаю значение ключ которого равен id языка

Comment: У вас сам var_key выглядит мягко говоря странно, как вы понимаете что вам нужен в данный момент 33_surname, а не 32_surname. Только не говорите, что 32 и 33 это ID неких других сущностей в БД..

Comment: Я вообще нифига не понял. Мой вам совет — не пилите свой велосипед и просто возьмите gettext, который юзается для перевода на большинстве известных мне сайтов

Comment: Не совсем понял в чем проблема с 32_surname и 33.Я в функцию translate() передаю var_key и он мне вытаскивает массив с вариантами перевода данной переменной.А дальше по id активного языка вытаскиваю из массива значение.

Comment: `gettext` http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

Answer (score 1):

структура БД - не правильно спроектирована,
если планируется статическое кол-во языков и переводы для большинства языков будут использоваться то вариант №1:

- таблица Texts (Поля text_id,  text_rus, text_eng, text_ukr)

плюсы меньше данных соответсвенно меньше времени занимает выборка.

минусы - не очень гибкое решение (не удобно добавлять, удалять новые языки), нельзя использовать языки для какихто других нужд.(например если будут еще не только тексты на разных языках а скажем еще новости то у вас в новостях опять же будут подобные колонки)

или вариант №2:

- таблица Languages (поля languages_id, name_of_language)
- таблица Texts (Поля text_id,  languages_id, text)

плюсы - гибкий вариант выбираем только те переводы которые нам нужны, без лишних данных, можно сделать каскадное удаление переводов при удалении языка, легко масштабировать при добавлении языков.
Легко масштабируемо....языки используются для любых других таблиц...нет дубликации языков как в варианте №1

минусы - больше времени выборки

Второй вариант однозначно лучше, для проектирования системы на будущее, первый вариант однозначно лучше..для громаднейших объемов информации в рамках одной таблицы.

В вашем случае лучше №2.

Comment: Я так понимаю структура таблицы Text  у вас такая же как у меня за исключением поля var_key.Только как в данном примере будет производиться поиск переменной по Id,как по мне это не лучший вариант а если удалят переменную  с таким id?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность не городить огород со своим переводчиком посмотрите `gettext`. Куча инструментов, монго приложений OpenSource ей пользуються так что можно будет просто позаимствовать файл с переводом.

Стандарт
https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

PHP
http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

Редактор для переводов:
https://poedit.net/

```
<?php
    // Set language to German
    putenv('LC_ALL=ru_RU');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');

    // Specify location of translation tables
    bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");
    // Choose domain
    textdomain("myPHPApp");

    // Translation is looking for in /locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo now

    // Use the  _() or gettext()
    // echo gettext("Have a nice day");
    echo _("Have a nice day");
```

Пример выведет:
    `Хорошего дня`

а если перевод не найден:
    `Have a nice day`

Comment: Спасибо ознакомлюсь

Comment: @quaresma89, не надо тратить время на этот бесполезный материал, там ничего нет по поводу того, как реализовать переводы из базы

Comment: @MasterAlex Все зависит от того какую проблему надо решить. Если нужна стандартная рабочая система перевода, то материал очень полезен. Если обязательно надо БД то ненужен. О чем я предупредил в первом предложении.

Comment: Да нужно именно с Бд,чтобы была возможность управлять из админки,а стандартный перевод можно релизовать и с помощью Кодигнайтера

Comment: @quaresma89 Мне ответ оставить для тех кото ищет по "перевод сайт пхп" или удалить?

Comment: Оставьте конечно

Comment: @E_p, в вопросе речь идёт именно про поля БД и скриншот из БД, так что вполне логичный вывод, что нужен пример того, как можно переводить с помощью БД :)

Comment: @MasterAlex Перечитайте название и все не так однозначно и понятно ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то придумал у себя в проекте такой вариант (если что на авторство не претендую, думаю похожих вариантов много на просторах сети), для новостей и статей хватает.

Так выглядит типовая ячейки базы с контентом на трёх языках, естественно что поля в базе нужно задавать размером побольше, если ожидается много текста:

`{"en":"News","ru":"Новости","es":"Noticias"}`

Допустим, что переменная, которая получает данные из базы называется `$title`, значит чтобы вывести данные на нужном языке, нужно обратиться к этой переменной `$title[$language]`, где `$language` - это переменная, в которой будет обозначение языка "en", "ru" или "es".

Естественно, в базе будет и таблица с языками, которая будет отдавать эти обозначения языков и другие данные для виджета языков, чтобы можно было легко переключать их на сайте.

В админке редактирование и добавление реализуется с помощью JS, который обрабатывает поля с разными языками и формирует нужный вид данных для переменной PHP.

Comment: Я хотел бы организовать структуру так чтобы запись содержала айди языка,чтобы потом было легко добавлять новые языка если понадобится,и чтобы не создавать лишние поля.

Comment: @quaresma89, а какая разница id это будет языка или его двухбуквенное обозначение? и да, при добавлении нового языка, лишнее поле в базе не создаётся, у меня уже 8 языков и всё работает как часы. А типовая ячейка базы выглядит так: `{"en":"News","ru":"Новости","es":"Noticias", "de":"News", "fr":"News", "jp":"News", "cn":"News", "pt":"News"}`

Comment: Хорошо это для простых переменных перевод,а если для каких то новосте или еще чего,будете хранить url_ro,text_ro и т.д? а если придется новый язык добавить,это сколько полей надо будет то

Comment: Или я вас возможно не правильно понял.Каждое поле в базе будь то text или url или еще чего содержит json ключ->язык,значение->перевод?

Comment: @quaresma89, да, именно это я пишу, каждое поле содержит все языки, независимо от количества текста и языков, добавление нового языка происходит при добавлении языка в таблицу языков и после пересохранения строки в БД, если не пересохранить, то показывает язык по умолчанию и в базе этого языка у поля не будет, всю систему расписывать не стал, там много всего, но суть пытаюсь объяснить, если интересно, то могу и подробнее расписать